# Can GFCI power strip use alone effectively with a non-GFCI socket or with a socket is not grounded properly?

Tags: electrical

I use a socket tester by MEET that indicate a group socket of 2 is not grounded properly. Someone suggest that I could replace a GFCI socket for adding Ground protection. I wonder, if using only a GFCI power strip without replacing with a GFCI socket, is it still effectively providing protection within its own circuit breaker or protection device?

Comment: what is GCFI ?.

Comment: It should provide protection to people using the devices plugged in the strip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace one of the two outlets with a GFCI outlet, the new GFCI outlet can protect the other outlet, with proper installation.
The GFCI power strip will not protect anything plugged into the outlets, it will only protect the devices plugged into the power strip. This is because the power strip doesn’t have the right connectivity to interrupt the flow of electricity between the outlets or from outlet to circuit breaker box..  GFCI outlet can interrupt the flow of electricity in the wall, with proper wiring, but the power strip is not able to do that.

To clarify, if you are installing GFCI outlet, the outlet typically comes with screws at the top covered in tape. Breaking that tape and using those screws will not lead to a “correctly grounded” situation.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Then I know how to choose and what to do next now.